# Whats the difference in sharepoint permission giving?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions

I am at my wit's end with this one.

I am not even sure how to explain this.

What's the difference between using the permissions access on the home page and the permissions access using site permissions?

When I add them from the home page (picture one), they don't show up in the site permissions page.

[image: Using the home page]

[image: Using site permissions]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first picture, you're adding them to the [Office 365 Group](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Learn-about-Office-365-groups-b565caa1-5c40-40ef-9915-60fdb2d97fa2) which it's membership is represented in the SharePoint site's Members group (by default). The second image is the classic SharePoint permissions management.

In general, leveraging the Office 365 Group is best practice. This membership will give them access to any associated resources, such as Teams, Planner, Stream, and so forth that is associated with the Group (and SharePoint site).

Comment: Thank you so much for shedding light on this. I have found no literature on the difference between these two methods. If you have any links I would appreciate it.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sharing-permissions-modern-experience might be of help.